# Fade in/out all html5 audio on section.active with fullpage.js

Tags: jquery, html, audio, fullpage.js

[Fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) allows audio (and video) to autoplay when its section is active. I have 10 sections with a different audio/video element on each, and would like the audio to fade in & out when the section becomes active/inactive.

I have play/pause/mute/unmute buttons set (and working) to fade the audio with this code, but would like the same to happen on transitions.

```
$('#mute').on('click', function() {
 $('body audio, body video').each(function() {
   $(this).animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function () {
        muted = true;
    });
 });
});
```

I found the relevant parts of the extension that control autoplaying/pausing, but can't seem to figure out how to properly fade in & out...either its permanently muting everything, or throwing page errors. I'm assuming that the right way to go about it is setting everything's volume at 0 globally from the start, and then animating volume to 1 if prop.play == true? Or something along those lines?

For autoplaying (line 1662):

```
//playing HTML5 media elements
        panel.find('video, audio').each(function(){
            var element = $(this).get(0);

            if( element.hasAttribute('data-autoplay') && typeof element.play === 'function' ) {
                element.play();
            }
        });
```

And autopausing (line 1700)

```
//stopping HTML5 media elements
        panel.find('video, audio').each(function(){
            var element = $(this).get(0);

            if( !element.hasAttribute('data-keepplaying') && typeof element.pause === 'function' ) {
                element.pause();
            }
        });
```

I have a very basic [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kemtmm9a/42/), and what I'm actually working on [is here](http://albums.cblls.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get into fullpage.js code to do it. In fact, you shouldn't if you want to keep updating to the latest fullPage.js version and so on.

You can remove the automatic play and pause and do it yourself by using [fullpage.js callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks).

To mute them you could do something like this:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        var leavingSection = $(this);

        leavingSection.find('audio, body video').each(function() {
           $(this).animate({volume: 0}, 1000, function () {
                muted = true;
            });
         });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, @alvaro! And thanks for building such a useful plugin!